# Remove div from HTML with specific Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML code and I want to remove some div with specific class and its content from HTML.
I have content dynamic. So I can not use directly remove function. I got this HTML in one variable. How Can I search and remove this.

For Example as below:

```
<div class="copyClipboard" style="float: left;padding-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;width: 100%;">
        <button id="target-to-copy" data-clipboard-target="clipboard-text">
            Click To Copy
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade imageModal" id="imageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">CTRL + C for Copy</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea name="forCopy" id="clipboard-text" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to remove Div with class name modal and whole content inside in it.

Please help me to remove this.

Comment: `$('.modal').remove()`?

Comment: You could have tried searching for something like `jQuery remove element`, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic content, you can use `.on` function e.g.

```
$(document).on('event', 'selector', function(){
      $('.modal').remove();
});
```

So, say e.g. event is click of a button then -

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
      $('.modal').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

//if dynamic content, remove on button click or some other event

```
$(".close").click(function(){  

$('.modal').remove();

});
```

//if you want to empty content inside div use this

```
$(".close").click(function(){    

$('.modal div').empty();

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this : as suggested by Arun. `.remove()` will remove the selected elements and all its children.

```
$('.modal').remove();
```

**[API Document for remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**

**EDIT** - If you are getting html in variable then you can use `.not()` and then `append()` to parent div. lets say parent div has `class="parentDiv"`

```
var htmlCode = '<div class="copyClipboard" style="float: left;padding-bottom: 20px;text-align: center;width: 100%;">
        <button id="target-to-copy" data-clipboard-target="clipboard-text">
            Click To Copy
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade imageModal" id="imageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">CTRL + C for Copy</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <textarea name="forCopy" id="clipboard-text" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';

$('div.parentDiv').append($(htmlCode).not('.modal'));
```

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/61r793yt/6/)**